# How can I block cards from being repeated in the same Anki session?

Tags: anki

If when studying a card I click "Again" I would like the option of omitting it from being re-presented in the same session even if the session lasts say 10 minutes, longer than the shortest repeat time, say 1 minute. (I am using Anki 2.1.)

The reason is that when I enter say 100 new cards, I would like to be able to open a session, run through all of the cards marking every card as "Again" even if I've remembered most of them well, close the session, and then do the same again one or more times later in the day, or the next day, before moving on to using Anki in the normal way. This is what I like to do right at the beginning, as a kind of informal memorisation session or test wherein each card is presented exactly once, and leaving every card at bottom level for the next session. It's annoying at this stage for some of the cards to be presented twice or more, because it can take a long time before I'm presented with the last few cards.

I suppose a workaround would be to set the first learning step at longer than the session length, but I was wondering whether there was a method that didn't require changing the learning step length.

I should add that minutes don't mean much to me where Anki is concerned because there is no device I'm running it on that I leave switched on all the time or that I want Anki attracting my attention from even when it is switched on. I plan to use Anki a few times each day when I get the chance, and to make cards in batches of 100 or so, and to review those cards a couple of times as described in the second paragraph before I let Anki do its thing with the spacing of repetition.

Answer (score 1):

You can create "Custom Study Session" and add cards from the deck you want to study:

[image]

Then click gear icon next to "Custom Study Session" and choose "Cards selected by Order Added"

[image]

Once you are done with your session all cards are returned to the original deck.

[image]

Hope that helps.